# I have the following code to create the body of an Outlook .ics file in C#

Tags: c#, html, outlook

```
HttpRequest request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
        string baseUrl = request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

var hLink = string.Format("{0}/Activities/Details?id={1}", baseUrl, responseDto.Id);

var sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append(@"X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN"">\n<HTML><BODY>");

sb.Append(string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", hLink, responseDto.Notes));

sb.Append("</BODY></HTML>");

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                writer.AutoFlush = true;

                //HEADER
                writer.WriteLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
                writer.WriteLine("VERSION:1.0");
                writer.WriteLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");

                //BODY
                writer.WriteLine("DTSTART:" + responseDto.Date.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"));
                writer.WriteLine("DTEND:" + responseDto.Date.AddHours(1).ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"));

                writer.WriteLine("SUMMARY:" + responseDto.ActivityType.Name);
                writer.WriteLine("DESCRIPTION:" + sb.ToString());

                //writer.WriteLine("LOCATION:" + responseDto.Location);

                //FOOTER
                writer.WriteLine("END:VEVENT");
                writer.WriteLine("END:VCALENDAR");

                writer.Flush();

                contentData = new byte[(int)memoryStream.Length];

                memoryStream.Position = 0;

                memoryStream.Read(contentData, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);

                return contentData;
            }

        }
```

The file is being created but the link is not displaying, instead, the entire contents of sb is rendered in the description:

```
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN”>
<HTML><BODY><a href=”http://localhost:58999/Activities/Details?id=5d018f0f-b45b-4797-8404-fb8bbf31331d”>Redwings</a></BODY></HTML>
```

I am new to C# and HTML so any input would help.

Thanks

Comment: It would help to know where you got this code from. Can you post a link or is it in a project you inherited?

Comment: It is sort of both.  I am reusing a code from one of our apps and i needed to add a Hyperlink inside the .ics file.  The codes I added are the string builder and the line that adds the string builder to the description.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to read because of the formatting.

> The file is being created but the link is not displaying, instead, the entire contents of sb is rendered in the description:

I don't see anywhere that you pass `contentData` from your **MemoryStream** into your StringBuilder.

Is some code missing?

Comment: This might explain it better:

sorry I wasn't very descriptive.

Comment: This code is part of a class that simply returns a byte type called contentData.

Comment: and it is called from here:
        
public ActionResult ExportToOutlook(Guid id)
        {
            var query = new GetActivityByIdQuery();
            var queryResult = query.Execute(id);

            var outlookCalendarFileCreator = new OutlookCalendarFileCreator();
            var contentData = outlookCalendarFileCreator.CreateOutlookCalendarFile(queryResult);

            var fileName = String.Format("{0}-Activity-{1}.ics", queryResult.ActivityType.Name, queryResult.Date) ;
            return File( contentData,"text/plain", queryResult.Notes + fileName);
        }

Answer (score 0):

That line must be

```
DESCRIPTION;X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html><body><a href="http://localhost:58999/Activities/Details?id=5d018f0f-b45b-4797-8404-fb8bbf31331d”>My link</a></body></html>
```

There must be ";", not ":" after DESCRIPTION, and your HTML must be valid, not just a url.

Comment: The value of sb.ToString does link  to a valid html. And it works if we copy that value and place it a browser. The problem is how do we make outlook render the html properly?
For example, the link is "www.stackoverflow.com",
how would the html look like?

thanks!

Comment: It is your responsibility to download HTML from that url and place it in the DESCRIPTION header.

Comment: Isn't that what this code does:

                writer.WriteLine("DESCRIPTION:" + sb.ToString());
where sb.toString is the HTML code? or do I have to do something else?

Comment: Ah, I see it, sorry. What about ";" vs. ":" after the DESCRIPTION header?

Comment: I tried that but all it did was to not display anything in the description.  
Thanks.

Comment: What is your latest ICS file? Can you post the whole thing?

Comment: @Dimitry Streblechenko: I posted a new question with the complete code.
Thanks.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018888/create-outlook-ics-file-in-c-sharp-with-hyperlink-inside